# remove Paypal create account in debit or credit card section

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I'm building a website and want to add "Paypal" payment method 
so I add this Html Form to site page

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"    target="paypal">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
 <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalemail@gmail.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="My Cart Item 1">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
 <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url"       value="http://localhost:2718/school/paymeant.aspx">

 <input type="hidden" name="return"  value="http://localhost:2718/school/paymeant.aspx?sucess=1">

 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost:2718/school/paymeant.aspx?faile=1">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

all is going ok expect when user want to pay me throw credit or master or visa card 
then paypal ask them to create account to pay throw that card how can i remove 
create account option in debit or credit card section

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using for adding a PayPal button to your is called [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/).  This integration method is quick and easy, but it has some limitations.

What you're after, where users can just pay with a credit card without logging in or creating an account, is called "guest checkout".  Unfortunately, with Payments Standard guest checkout relies on browser based cookies.  As such, if anybody has ever signed in to a PayPal account with that particular browser the system is going to assume you'll be using PayPal, so it sort of hides away the guest checkout option.  You should still see a link that allows you to get there, but it's very easy to miss.

If you were to try that in a fresh browser or clear the cache/cookies in your current browser you would probably see the guest checkout experience.

If you want to force the guest checkout experience at all times regardless of browser cookies you'll need to use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) instead of Payments Standard.  This will require the use of a programming language like PHP.

Assuming you are familiar with that, you could use this [PHP PayPal SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to easily [integrate Express Checkout](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-express-checkout-php-demo-sample/).  It comes with free samples that would probably be enough to get you going.

Alternatively, if you are using a CMS of some kind there is probably a plugin available that would make Express Checkout integration easy for you.  For example, if you're using WooCommerce, by chance, I would recommend taking a look at [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://www.angelleye.com/product/woocommerce-paypal-plugin/).